# Spring 2.5 form/jsp encoding problem

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, character-encoding

I'm facing a really annoying problem:I created a form with spring's form-tags and when I insert text with non-latin characters I get a sequence of questionmarks.I've used the CharacterEncodingFilter in my web.xml but I'm still facing the same problem,I've set characterEncoding in UTF-8 at the formBackingObject method of my controller,I've set page encoding charset and enctype to UTF-8 with no result.I know there are similar posts here and I've tried the suggested solutions but nothing changed!Any suggestions? thank you in advance

Comment: So, you're storing and retrieving data in a DB?

Comment: yes and my data are stored as question marks!

Answer (score 4):

A sequence of question marks is typical when either the DB encoding or the HTTP response encoding cannot accept the obtained bytes for the encoding it was instructed to use.

Since you've set the page encoding to UTF-8, the HTTP response encoding part is fine (assuming that all you did was putting `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>` in top of JSP).

So, the DB encoding is suspect. You need to ensure that the DB is been instructed to use the proper encoding to store the characters. You're supposed to do this in `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements. With some JDBC drivers you also need to pass an extra argument in JDBC connection string to specify the encoding the bytes are transferred in. The details depends on the DB and JDBC driver used, so it's up to you to consult the appropriate manuals. If you stucks, update your question to include the DB make/version used.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) - [Section about Databases](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases)

Comment: thank you for your answer.I forgot to mention that I use hibernate with mysql.But when I print the values -via system.out.println- before they are stored in the database I get the question-mark-sequence.So is this a problem of  system.out.println?Or in fact I'm doing something worng before the database part?

Comment: This is another problem, yes. You need to instruct the logger/stdout to use UTF-8 as well. See also the "Development environment" section in the linked article.

Comment: ok!I'm reading the article you mention at the moment,I will try what you said and I'll let you know!Thank you for your help! :)